# Windows server 2008 R2 Web and Aero

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, aero

Does server 2008 R2 **Web** support such themes as Basic or Aero (not Classic) over RDP?

I cannot find any documents and I cannot enable it for Web edition.

Comment: Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on http://serverfault.com

Comment: OK, I will check serverfault.